# Trigger distant camera using 3.3V

Tags: converter, 3.3v, 24v

I need to trigger a camera using a 3.3V signal, the camera is at the end of a 3 meter cable. This camera has two trigger inputs, a 3.3V GPIO input and an optocoupler input with max input of 30V. I guess that the 3.3V signal will not work with a 3 meter cable so I should use a higher voltage. I happen to have a 24V power supply available. So I guess it will be better to trig the camera using a 24V signal. If I'm right, how can I easily convert the 3.3V signal into 24V? The trig frequency is just a couple per second so I don't think I need a especially fast circuit.

EDIT: maybe it would be better to lower the 24V to something lower like 12V or 6V, right?

The circuit on the camera side is:
[image]

Comment: 3.3v will be fine over 3m

Comment: Its an electrically noisy environment and the testing I made some time ago, I lost some trigs and got a few unexpected ones.

Comment: Try a 100nF cap in the connector, camera side, and a ferrite clamp on the cable.

Comment: Use shielded cable.

Comment: Also consider adding an RC filter on the camera side, to reduce noise. I have done this with great success on x-ray test systems that have 100kW of power within 1m of the trigger cable running 5v logic levels.

Comment: @PedroNF Do you know what the current limiter does in terms of limiting the current? (It's probably a very safe level. I'm just wondering if they provide a spec for it.) Separately, why not wire the +24 V at your remote end straight to pin 2 over the cable and then switch the low-side (pin 5) to your MCU ground? Just a simple NPN BJT or NFET should be able to handle the opto-current okay and it doesn't require any fancy 24 V footwork -- just a BJT or FET that can stand off the 24 V (which most can do.)

Comment: @PedroNF  Also, have you considered [DIY LoRa camera triggers](https://www.hackster.io/news/build-your-own-ultra-long-range-remote-camera-trigger-8c3c9b0c71e)? More range and flexibility as your needs evolve over time. Not a lot of cost. Looks interesting. (I'm going to use LoRa for something entirely different. So this is just a vague curiosity of mine.)

Comment: @jonk Isn't it the same, switching on the low side (pin 5) to ground, instead of switching the 24V on pin 2? In terms of electrical noise issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the circuit below and its working ok.
The line coming from the left into R3 is the 24V power supply.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This. Unsure if your opto input already includes that resistor.

Make sure to pick a MOSFET with a rated RSdon for a Vgs of at least 3.3V, and that it's source-drain voltage can withstand at least 30V.

Might want to connect a TVS diode from gate to ground too since it sounds like this thing can be unplugged leaving the gate vulnerable to ESD.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fg8Tib.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Yes, the cable from the trigger device to the camera can be disconnected.

Comment: Just edited the question to include the camera side circuit, apparently there is already a current limiter so no need for a resistor.